# How would a delayed discovery of the New World affect both sides?

Tags: warfare, economy, alternate-history, strategy

I'll try to make this simple.

I am developing a world where for some reason two separate land masses (like Europe and America) are separated by a mass ocean and one civilization group on one continental mass is modern tech level and one civilization on the other continent is just entering the Renaissance era. **If the two sides meet during a global war fought on the high-tech continent what would the military and economic impacts be? Would there be a mad scramble to conquer the Renaissance continental mass?**

Assume a condition similar to WWII with an island nation (similar to England) and a fading empire (similar to the Soviets) against an all-conquering evil empire.

Comment: For the record both sides have nukes but have signed nonaggression treaties. They have known about the Renaissance continents for a while since satellites but they did not have the resources to send many people over at the time and polytheistic natives drove the colonists out.

Comment: Is tech level the *only* difference? When the Americas were conquered, there was a certain "We are better than them" mentality which is now wrong in the modern world. (*Slaves, Inequality, etc..*)

Comment: @DoubleDouble besides the obvious religious, cultural and societal differences that come from being separated from each other for thousands of years the only difference is tech level.The Renaissance side is polytheistic and feudalistic and the Modern side has the mentality that we do today.

Comment: Nukes in the Renaissance era? How's that possible?

Comment: @HDE226868 I meant the modern era side of the pond. The two sides 'Russians' and 'British' vs a type of 'Nazi Germany' setup. This is not Earth, just a similar world.

Comment: Illness killed vastly more people than war did during the Columbian Exchange on both sides, but wiped out the majority of people in the Americas.

Comment: How do "satellites" and "nukes" work together with the lack of resources to send people over? I mean US efforts to build a fleet to send the troops in WWII is certainly a huge task but nothing compared to the Manhattan Project?

Comment: If it's WW2 they probably don't have satellites yet. Maybe nukes. Also, small detail, USSR was not a fading power at that time.

Comment: @Vincent tldr; Tech level is modern, war situation is similar to WWII, USSR-like society on one end, not Earth

Comment: @DustinJackson - I hit some disbelief in this setup...the second your England like nation hit sea faring abilities to navigate the ocean, they would have been all over that renaissance island, trading, taking wealth as their own, taking slaves, etc...imperialism is a bitch to those on the receiving end.

Comment: I'm with @Twelfth here, it would be illogical for there to be no contact with a sizeable New World. Just the mineral wealth alone would drive prospectors and wild-catters across the oceans... Armed with machineguns and easily resupplied from home, these private citizens would act the part of Cortez and Pizzaro.

Comment: Worth noting: Orson Scott Card touched on a similar theme--though taken in a very different direction--in *Pastwatch: The Redemption of Christopher Columbus*.  It's definitely worth reading.

Comment: How the hell you managed to get _nukes_ during Renaissance? Those are some extremely steampunky nukes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setup seems a bit unrealistic...in a single word "Imperialism".  The modernish England nation you describe has full access to the seas and presumably has had them for a while now if they are in a WWII era.  Yet somehow they've completely ignored the unknown renaissance continent and this starkly contradicts history here on Earth.  This renaissance continent is presumably rich in some resource that the English island here is not...be it gold/wealth, spices/luxuries, or even people/labor.  It actually leaves me feeling that the only way this setup could have come to be is the English island is so incredibly wealthy and contains all the resources it would want or need.  Had the English island needed resources, they would have gone and taken them from this Renaissance island a long time ago.

I would think pressing people into service from the Renaissance continent, especially if the big evil is winning, is quite likely.  They might not make the best soldiers, but a body is a body.

If you stick to the setup...my answer is a no.  There is no need or rush to conquer this renaissance continent as the war will be decided on the modern content (if conquering the renaissance continent is a goal, then that can happen after the war is won).  There could be a diplomatic rush to it and attempt to secure help to fight the big evil though.

Answer (score 2):

(*My answer is making some assumptions, in that the lower-tech society is not yet involved in the war and they are in the opposite direction than the enemy. By placing them in the opposite direction we would want the minimum number of troops possible there, opposed to turning it into a staging area*)

I would imagine that the modern society would very quickly attempt to *persuade* the Renaissance society to set up production and extraction of any war supplies they may be able to produce - by offering to help build and greatly advance their technology.

"Look that issue you have there, let us solve it and also give us this land here to make a production/extraction facility and allow us to hire your people as laborers."

On the renaissance society's side is where things get a lot trickier. They may trust or be distrustful. Different factions may side with the enemy or with us, or want to stay neutral. The war could easily split the society into two or more sides. You could even end up with only a weaker group agreeing to produce weapons, but the technology trading would allow them to quickly grow in power, causing all kinds of political issues.

---

Only if the modern society **needs** the resources from the newly discovered island, and the renaissance society refuses, will they conquer by force. With modern technology of cameras, internet, etc it would be very hard to ignore whats happening on the island. They would be fighting against a conquering nation by.. conquering another nation - just doesn't seem to make much sense. If the enemy are really trying to conquer the world, the renaissance society should be able to tell the danger to themselves over time and decide to help eventually.

Answer (score 1):

## Prelude

> If the two sides meet during a global war fought on the high-tech continent what would the military and economic impacts be?

I think it would be the other way around. The high-tech side is much more likely to have developed ways of crossing the ocean (boats, aircraft, etc.) than the Renaissance-era side, and they likely developed them much earlier. So I'd bet that the high-tech side would invade first, *before* any of this happened.

But you mentioned a global war, so I'll go back to what could happen on the high-tech continent.

Things the high-tech folks wouldn't have to worry about:

- Aerial bombing
- Missiles
- Surveillance

They would have advantages

- . . . on land, with better artillery, land vehicles . . . oh, and guns! That's a biggie.
- . . . at sea, or on the water. Their boats would be bigger and faster, and they could avoid close battles by simply using torpedoes.
- . . . in the air, because they have air power and the low-tech folks don't.

The low-tech folks would have advantages

- . . . in . . . um . . . Actually, they don't really have any. I guess that their weapons could make them easier to conceal, but that's not a huge advantage.

## How it plays out on the high-tech continent:

Predicting war is a tough thing, but I can imagine what would happen in an assault on the high-tech continent (presumably by ships, at first):

1. The high-tech guys place mines near places they think the boats will land, and place submarines further out. They'll have concealment aplenty. The Renaissance folks won't know what hits them. For any ships reaching shore, they'd get a warm welcome as Allied soldiers did on the beaches of Normandy. Except they'd have no way of fighting back.
2. There are some spots where, by shear luck, the Renaissance guys will get in. The high-tech response could be to simply line up a bunch of guys with machine guns - or bring together a platoon of armored vehicles - and mow down the attackers. A more efficient way would be to bomb the areas to smithereens, but that would destroy precious land.
3. The Renaissance guys will realize that they're hopelessly outgunned on land, and they have no speed on the sea. Any boats they send out will be overtaken by the boats of the high-tech navies. Their best option? A quick retreat.

## How it plays out on the low-tech continent:

Eventually, the tide will turn, and war will go to the land of the low-tech folks. I would not like to be there when it happens, because all hell will break loose.

1. A naval assault will be necessary (by the high-tech guys) to establish bases. Capture coastal towns and cities; these will be well-defended but easy to breach by shear force. They need to be completely abandoned so they can e re-purposed; allow *everyone* to live if it means that they'll leave.
2. Use these cities as airbases. Aircraft carriers can shuttle planes to them. For small craft, you don't need proper runways. During WWII, pilots made use of what they had. Larger bombers can then fly over to the bases, and restock. They then prepare for the next stage.
3. The cheapest and quickest option is a strategic bombing campaign. The purpose here is more fear than devastation, although destruction works, too. The high-tech guys can drop bombs wherever they want; it'll scare the hell out of the locals. Heck, all you need is to show a *picture* of an atomic explosion to a villager, and they'll pretty much surrender. The high-tech folks need to intimidate. Strategic bombing can help that. Try to avoid civilian targets, though. Keep casualties down.

I think the war will end pretty quickly. Casualties could be pretty low, for a global war. You don't *need* nuclear weapons to scare the Renaissance society into submission.

## Aftermath

If it was a one-on-one conflict, things would be pretty simple. But it's not. You have multiple groups on both sides, which is where things get really nasty really quickly.

> Would there be a mad scramble to conquer the Renaissance continental mass?

*Now* there will be. From the side of the conquerors, the land is free for the taking. It's going to be exactly like what happened in the New World on *our* Earth - except the people being conquered are already scared as heck of the conquerors.

There could be a peaceful (relatively) you-take-this-and-we'll-take-this kind of deal between the high-tech folks, or they could just squabble amongst each other. Treaties could solve this, because the future would be laid out. I highly doubt, though, that the folks who have just been invaded will all be unified. How will they figure out who can represent the whole continent?

Which brings me to *another* point. I've simplified this whole thing a lot. The war isn't going to end at the same point everywhere, especially if the Renaissance people are more of a confederation than a unified nation. Heck, they're feudalistic!

The war will continue, no matter how many treaties are signed. Pockets of fighting will continue, and rebels will pop back up every now and then. But they'll be crushed. Renaissance technology will never beat the technology we have to day.

Answer (score 1):

If vaccines and antibiotics have been discovered by the time of contact than I guess things could go very differently. There would still be the exchange of illnesses, but they might be better treated and contained. If that happened then the Renaissance New World would be in a better position to resist conquest than in our world.

It would be a mad rush to find allies (Mexico is called Mexico for a reason) and advantageous trading positions as well as military positions on both sides. Really the situation described is in many ways closer to perhaps China, Japan, Korea area of Asia in the 1800's relative to the European Great Powers than the discovery of the New World, at least in my opinion. They would be willing to engage in gunboat diplomacy but if asked most americans may vaguely be aware that the US took the Philippians, perhaps remember something about Japan, and aren't likely to know anything about Korea.

From the point of view of the high tech side the low tech side is not at all a threat, but they are players that need to be pinned down as to where they are and contained or undermined to get the right results relative to markets and military objectives. The high tech players can operate at will in the low tech space, but likely do not have the resources or desire to hold and administer that space themselves so the low tech states become clients of one of the sides or the other and then are played against each other, likely along already existing geo-political fault lines (or someone decides to be UK and conquer everything because they can). (See the Third World during the Cold War, and why it was called the Third World in the first place.)

As happened in the Cold War and during the age of the European Great Powers (really what led to WWI and II); some of those Renaissance states aren't going to be happy suddenly being small players and are going to be doing everything they can to be or seem to be a real player themselves, see for example, China, North Korea, Japan in WW2, Iran, South Africa, India, so forth.